# Search inside array using Elastic Search

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am using Elastic version 6.8, created one index into whose schema is as follow:

```
{
"properties": {
    "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
            "raw": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    },
    "tags": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "fields": {
            "raw": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

and I have added following documents into it

```
    [{
    "title": "one",
    "tags": ["html", "css", "javascript"]
    }, {
    "title": "two",
    "tags": ["java", "jsp", "servlet"]
   }, {
    "title": "three",
    "tags": ["spring", "java"]
   }, {
    "title": "four",
    "tags": ["react", "angular", "javascript"]
   }, {
    "title": "five",
    "tags": ["java"]
   }, {
    "title": "six",
    "tags": []
   }]
```

now I have more than 10 millions document in elastic search. Now I want to search following cases:

1. List all tags. with unique result (using skip, limit) skip value change but limit is fixed.so here I want result like

   html,
   css,
   javascript,
   java,
   jsp,
   servlet,
   spring,
   react,
   angular
2. Partil search inside tags, it means if I search using **act** then it should give result as : **react**  this also using skip limit.

How I can get this using Elastic search query. please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can find unique possible value by using term aggregation.

```json
GET yourindex/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "all_tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tags",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- "size":100 Get at most 100 unique values. Default is 10. You can increase more but it will include cost. You can check more on doc.
- For partial search you can use wildcard query OR you can try N-Gram Tokeninzer. Both will allow to do partial search but wildcard query will be costly. You can evaluate according to your use case.

Comment: can you please give any example for partial search?

Comment: for partial search can I use query like this: {"query_string":{"query":"*test*","fields":["tags.raw"],"default_operator":"OR"}}

Comment: Yes you can make a partial search on "text" field but you need to check how your data has been indexed and also which terms has been produced. "text" field having standard analyzer as a default. So you can check how it produces the terms while indexing and you can perform search accordingly.

Comment: can we merge aggregation and partial search query, it means aggregation query will return only those result with match search conditions. if this possible can you please share any example for this?